# Get Element value from Ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm new to Jquery and Ajax calls... This is my call:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "some url",
    success: function(response){
      console.log(response);
    }  
  })
});
```

The console log show this response:

```
{"2014/08/08":[{},{"TEST":0}]}
```

How can I save the value of `TEST` to a variable?

Similar to `var t = document.getElementById('test').value`

Comment: `response["2014/08/08"][1].TEST`

Comment: it'll be `response.TEST` or `response[0].Test`.. you should be able to see it in the console and break down through it.

Comment: Now do `console.log(typeof response)` and tell us if you get `object` or `string` ?

Comment: @adeneo, It comes back as a string

Comment: Exactly, you don't have an object at all, so none of the answers will work. You have to add `dataType : "JSON"`

Comment: if you not set dataType is JSON, you can use JSON.parse to convert string to json data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `JSON.parse`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "some url",
    success: function(response){
      try{
        json = JSON.parse(response);
        test = null;
        $.each(json,function(i,item){
            test = item[1].TEST;
        });
        alert(test);//this is what you want
      }catch(e){}
    }  
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The response from the server is json, so the best way to handle it is to tell `jQuery` to expect a json answer and turn it into a regular javascript object. This is done by adding the `dataType: 'json'` to your `$.ajax(...)` call :

   ```
   $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "some url",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(response){
       console.log(response);
     }  
   })
   ```

   You can alternatively use the shortcut [`$.getJSON(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) :

   ```
   $.getJSON("some url", function(response){ console.log(response); });
   ```
2. Now that you have a regular javascript object, you can use what other answers suggest :

   ```
   success: function(response) {
       console.log(response["2014/08/08"][1].TEST);
       // or
       $.each(response, function(i, itm) {
            console.log(itm[1].TEST);
       };
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$.each(response,function(i,value){
   alert(value[1].Test);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

*"want to save the value of TEST to a variable"* Try this:

```
var t = response["2014/08/08"][1].TEST;
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/ufryzpe8/3/)